# How to downgrade Vue version from 3 to 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, downgrade

I am using Vue3 for studying but it cannot support Vuetify library. So I need to downgrade it to version 2. How can I do that?
Vue3 is not installed in global. And vue-cli is installed in global, which is version 4.5.15.

Comment: You can choose Vue version when a new project is initialized with Vue CLI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

However, if you have components you have to update their code also.

Answer (score 2):

**1 INSTALL VUE JS 2**

```js
npm install vue@2.x.x
```

**2 UPDATE YOUR VUE-LOADER**

```js
npm update vue-loader
```

**3  if it is not installed, install it**

```js
npm i vue-loader
```

**4 install vue/compiler-sfc**

```js
npm add vue@next
npm add @vue/compiler-sfc -D
```